# Spring Boot Application immediately shuts down after starting in external TOMCAT

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

Spring boot  immediately shuts down after starting in external TOMCAT. But in Eclipse this runs well and JAR with embed too.

I use Tomcat 7 and JAVA 8.
I read a lot of webs and documentation which do not exist.

My Eclipse POM is:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.suez.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>Myapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>Myappname</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>com.suez.demo.SuezApplication</start-class>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
         <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.notnoop.apns</groupId>
        <artifactId>apns</artifactId>
         <version>1.0.0.Beta6</version>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
         <version>0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>           
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <generatePackage>com.suez.demo.ws</generatePackage>
                <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>*.wsdl</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin> 

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Tomcat output log last lines are:

```
2018-06-29 10:27:37.874  INFO 640 --- [ost-startStop-3] com.suez.demo.SuezApplication            : Started SuezApplication in 29.104 seconds (JVM running for 91.714)
2018-06-29 10:27:37.905  INFO 640 --- [ost-startStop-3] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@75e8c829: startup date [Fri Jun 29 10:27:11 CEST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-06-29 10:27:37.936  INFO 640 --- [ost-startStop-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2018-06-29 10:27:37.952  INFO 640 --- [ost-startStop-3] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Try to run tomcat by command line to get any error outputs not reported in logs.

Comment: if you want to run with external tomcat, you should remove dependency of embedded tomcat and exclude it from spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say out of the information you've provided, but what looks suspicious to me is that you're using spring-boot-starter-web which in turn brings tomcat starter transitively.

I see that the packaging of this module is WAR, so its intended to run in an external web container, but on the other hand, you say that it runs fine in "JAR with embed too". 
So it's a little bit confusing.

I've never by myself deployed spring boot application as a WAR file, but I believe you can go to [Start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io/) and generate a sample application that will package itself into WAR. This option is not shown by default, so you'll have to click on "switch to the full version" link

Comment: Hi @Mark, thanks for answer. For deploy JAR I change WAR to JAR in POM and delete 'provided' from spring-boot-starter-tomcat as tell in oficial docs of spring boot deployment WAR. I have do a lot of tryies without success, included redo the project and omite spring-boot-starter-web dependence.

Comment: Tomcat error logs from war: Jun 29, 2018 1:14:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Jun 29, 2018 1:14:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Suez-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] startup failed due to previous errors.

Comment: I think in the war you somehow end up with tomcat related jars. ( just open up a war and check what's in WEB-INF/lib there. if you see tomcat stuff it's bad, because these classes can clash between container classes and your applications classes. I think that when you'll check an example application from start.spring.io you won't find any tomcat related stuff in the war

Comment: of course to track the jars you can use mvn dependency:tree command, but it's a different story :)